Face Swapping Project related query
so I am working on a project in which a user takes a cola bottle scans a QR code in it clicks or uploads his/her image, and gets an output image in which he is posing with that cola bottle with a different background. As the source image changes the output image also changes along with its pose and background. So could you please help me with some ideas and some GitHub links and repositories with this similar project?
To Know about any similar project made on this topic or any Github links or repositories available so I can take some ideas from them because I am totally stuck.
